# Cannot add new entity in EF after DB restore

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

In .NET6 web API using EF and MSSQL Server Management Studio I cannot add new entities to DB after DB has been restored.

It just happened that I needed to drop DB and recreate and restore it from backup (full backup). But than problems starts.

Steps I have taken:

1. in Visual Studio I removed all files for migrations, including ContextModelSnapshot.cs
2. in Microsof SQL Server Management Studio I deleted DB manually: Databases -> right click on selected DB -> Delete. DB has been deleted.
3. In Visual Studio I run `add-migration initial` and than `update-database`. Database has been created and recreatedbut with no data inside.
4. In SSMS right click on DB -> Tasks/Restore/Database.
5. Than options tab `Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)` and `Close existing connections to destination database` -> OK -> database has been restored and now has all data from backup.

Nice!

...not really.

When I try to modify entity or add new one migration itself goes well and migration file shows current changes `Up` and `Down` but running `update-database` throws a `There is already an object named 'xxx' in the database` this way I cannot restore DB and proceed with further development 'cause it's blocking me from adding new entities or editing current ones.

I've have been unable to find a solution for that so any help appreciated.

SSMS: v.18.12.1
.NET: v6

Comment: Restoring the database from a backup should have no impact on the migrations in the application. The list of applied migrations is stored in the database itself. IMHO restore all your migrations from source control.

Comment: There's not a lot of information. Everything up to `not really` can be reduced to just `I restored an older backup.` There's no code, no list of migrations, no list of previous migrations, no data from the `__EFMigrationsHistory`, assuming it even exists. EF migrations aren't a database schema DIFF tool or even a production DB deployment tool. Their purpose is to make it easier to modify your model/database during development. They're not suitable for production. You *can* use them if you're very careful to only apply *simple* schema changes through migrations, and maintain the history.

Comment: I'd expect migrations to fail if you tried to `upgrade-database` on a database that contains the application's tables already but not `__EFMigrationHistory`. You can't use migrations without that table, because they contain a list of which migrations were already applied. EF depends on that to decide which migrations to execute and which to skip. Migrations are essentially SQL scripts generated from model changes, eg CREATE TABLE xxx, ALTER TABLE xxx. Without the history table EF can't guess which scripts to ignore, so it stops instead of making potentially catastrophic changes

Comment: If you want something that compares the current and target schemas, use Azure Data Studio's Database Project to generate a [`dacpac` package of the schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?view=sql-server-ver16) and publish it to the target either through a wizard or the [sqlpackage tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver16). The tools will compare the source and target schemas and generate the proper ALTER commands, just as Schema Compare does

Comment: PS: SSMS is just a client tool that connects to all SQL Server versions. Its version number says nothing about the SQL Server version you actually use. Is it SQL Server 2019? 2022? An older version?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is no list of migrations because as I said the migrations were deleted. Data in `__EFMigrationsHistory` contains thtables that backup has. I know that SSMS is no production development tool and as I said it's used in development - not production. Currently I am not using any migrations because they were deleted in order to restore DB and not to have constraints between DB backup and migrations so it would be 'clean'.

Comment: After backup (with deleted migrations) database is restored with all necessary data. Including new entity fails but as You said 'You can't use migrations without that table, because they contain a list of which migrations were already applied' I am not using migrations without that table because table exists and this is the content of the error I am facing now.

Comment: The database isn't clean. That's what the error tells you . Without any information (tables, __EFMigrationsHistory  contents, migrations specified in your project) it's impossible to help. Post enough code so people can reproduce the problem. `removed all files for migrations` does that mean that the table says there are 10 migrations but the project says there aren't any? That's an invalid state too, now EF *knows* the database wasn't modified by it